# Comparing int and string in DeepDiff (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, types, automated-tests

I use `deepdiff` package for comparing dictionaries.

When I make `DeepDiff({key: 0}, {key: "0"})` it returns an error about type, it's ok.

But when I try to ignore the type difference by parameter `ignore_type_in_groups=[(str, int)]` it also returns an error but now about value `Value of root changed from 0 to "0".`

Is it possible to ignore type difference fully by some native settings?

I found only parameter `number_to_string_func` in its manual, but it seems rather strange when there is not native ability for type ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

I read the complete deepdiff document from pypi.org. There is no such options available. For ignoring options, both should be number types. For instance one number can be float and another number can be integer. In this case, you can ignore type. So the way I suggest is:

```
for x in dict1.keys():
    x = str(x)
for x in dic2.keys():
    x = str(x)
```

Convert into string as mentioned above and compare.

Comment: It doesn't change anything